# CSS align an image to the left of a textbox

Tags: html, image, css

I am new to HTML and CSS and I am wondering how I can put an image directly to the left of a textbox. For this the image must have the same height as the textbox and the overall picture has to be centered. This is the code I already have written:

```css
div {
    margin: auto;
    width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 25px 50px 500px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://climate.nasa.gov/system/feature_items/images/28_global_ice_viewer.jpg">
<div> Textbox </div>
```

How do I make an image the same size as the box next to it and how do i align/put this image next to the left-border of this rectangle. The overall block has to be in the center.

Comment: You can add this image and div together in a table and write a css code to center the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `flex` property of CSS and adjust the image as a background image to make in align center to the div. Heres the code :

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.image {
  flex: 1;
  background-image: url("https://climate.nasa.gov/system/feature_items/images/28_global_ice_viewer.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>How do I make an image the same size as the box next to it and how do i align/put this image next to the left-border of this rectangle. The overall block has to be in the center.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```